# Delphi Firemonkey, show rectangle on landscape mode Android

Tags: delphi, orientation, firemonkey, landscape

how to display a rectangle containing TEdit in landscape position, when TEdit set focus on portrait mode? I use code like this, but in landscape position, Tedit is covered by the keyboard when Tedit sets focus on portrait.

```
procedure TForm1.RestorePosition; begin   VertScrollBox1.ViewportPosition := PointF(VertScrollBox1.ViewportPosition.X, 0);   Layout1.Align := TAlignLayout.Client;   VertScrollBox1.RealignContent; end;

procedure TForm1.UpdateKBBounds; var   LFocused : TControl;   LFocusRect: TRectF; begin   FNeedOffset := False;   if Assigned(Focused) then   begin
    LFocused := TControl(Focused.GetObject);
    LFocusRect := LFocused.AbsoluteRect;
    LFocusRect.Offset(VertScrollBox1.ViewportPosition);
    if (LFocusRect.IntersectsWith(TRectF.Create(FKBBounds))) and
       (LFocusRect.Bottom > FKBBounds.Top) then
    begin
      FNeedOffset := True;
      Layout1.Align := TAlignLayout.Horizontal;
      VertScrollBox1.RealignContent;
      Application.ProcessMessages;
      VertScrollBox1.ViewportPosition :=
        PointF(VertScrollBox1.ViewportPosition.X,
               LFocusRect.Bottom - FKBBounds.Top);
    end;   end;   if not FNeedOffset then
    RestorePosition; end;

procedure TForm1.FormFocusChanged(Sender: TObject); begin   UpdateKBBounds; end;

procedure TForm1.FormVirtualKeyboardHidden(Sender: TObject;   KeyboardVisible: Boolean; const Bounds: TRect); begin   FKBBounds.Create(0, 0, 0, 0);   FNeedOffset := False;   RestorePosition; end;

procedure TForm1.FormVirtualKeyboardShown(Sender: TObject;   KeyboardVisible: Boolean; const Bounds: TRect); begin   FKBBounds := TRectF.Create(Bounds);   FKBBounds.TopLeft := ScreenToClient(FKBBounds.TopLeft);   FKBBounds.BottomRight := ScreenToClient(FKBBounds.BottomRight);   UpdateKBBounds; end;

procedure TForm1.CalcContentBoundsProc(Sender: TObject;
                                       var ContentBounds: TRectF); begin   if FNeedOffset and (FKBBounds.Top > 0) then   begin
    ContentBounds.Bottom := Max(ContentBounds.Bottom,
                                2 * ClientHeight - FKBBounds.Top);   end; end;


procedure TForm1.Edit1Click(Sender: TObject); begin focus := 'edit1'; end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject); begin   if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXVirtualKeyboardToolbarService, IInterface(FService1)) then   begin
    FService1.SetToolbarEnabled(True);
    FService1.SetHideKeyboardButtonVisibility(True);   end;   VertScrollBox1.OnCalcContentBounds := CalcContentBoundsProc; end;
```

I want to show rectangle contains tEdit in landscape position when TEdit setfocus in potrait mode. Thank you very much

Comment: Are you under android/ios ? i m not sure what you are trying to do but maybe you can try https://github.com/Zeus64/alcinoe. on Android, when you select one Tedit and go in landscape then the edit fill all the available space (see the demo)

Comment: Thank you sir, can you help me where i can find the source code 
 only ALFmxControls.apk on zeus web? when I download zip, the file size is too large

Comment: Did you checked sample project in Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\Samples\Object Pascal\Multi-Device Samples\User Interface\ScrollableForm ?

Comment: yes sir i did. but in that example embarcadero turns off the rotation function. so we can't know how it looks when landscape mode when edit1 is focused.